# flow continue after exception catch

Tags: java, exception

why flow continue after `exception` catch? when i click button, toast show me message but after flow continue....

I show you my code!

```
     public static int showResult2(View v) {
            int totalAmount = 0;


            for (Birra b : biAdapter.getBox()) {
                if (b.selected) {
                    try {
                        int quantitaInt = Integer.parseInt(b.getQuantità());
                        totalAmount += b.distance * quantitaInt;

                    }catch(NumberFormatException exc){
                        System.out.println(exc);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "inserisci una quantita' a \""+b.name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
break;

                    }
                }
            }
            return totalAmount;
        }
```

IN ANOTHER CLASS I RECALL THE METHOD:

```
 ThreeFragment tf = new ThreeFragment();

                    string4 = tf.showResult(v);
                    try {
                    totalebibite = tf.showResult2(v);
                } catch (NumberFormatException exc) {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Because you don't break the loop. Add `break;` in the catch; or put the `try/catch` around the loop.

Comment: i used break; into catch after toast but doesn't work

Comment: I'm a bit confused why a quantity of beer would be a string in the first place (unless you're storing it as `"enough for a great night out"`, of course). Why not just change the type of `Birra.getQuantità()` to `int`?

Comment: i make cast String to int

Answer (score 0):

You've *caught* the exception, so Java assumes that you are going to deal with it adequately.

If you don't want that behaviour, aside from not `catch`ing it at all, you could always rethrow the exception (`throw exc;`) after you've printed your message, which means that something higher up the call stack ought to deal with it, or use a `break;` statement to end the loop early.

Comment: i used break; into catch after toast but doesn't work

Comment: Oh yes it will! We'll need to see the *exact* code, else we don't know where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to break your loop in exception use like the below.

You should add your break; in catch

break; is what you need to break out of any looping statement like for, while or do-while.

Still if it's comes meant make sure you are not calling this method again and again.

Also check in your Java class that you have any other method is using the same for loop condition.

You should not call your fragment classes. It's a wrong way to call a method.

```
  ThreeFragment tf = new ThreeFragment();
                        string4 = tf.showResult(v);               
                        totalebibite = tf.showResult2(v);
```

It's a static method call your method in this way

```
 ThreeFragment.showResult2(v);
```

Check this showResult(v); has the same for loop

Comment: then you should check your class file completely. Because break statement will work in catch block too.  Make sure how many times you are calling this method. If you are not calling this method frequently then you are not facing this issue because of this method @user6612196

Comment: i call this method in another class on click button

Comment: Check now @user6612196

Comment: the result of method showResult2(v) in which variable i must put it?

Comment: Exactly what is your issue. for loop always running even you used break am I right?

Answer (score 0):

The below piece of code is similar to what you have presented. As pointed by others, break; ends the nearest loop.

```
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        if(true) {      
            try{
                //Your logic here, which could throw exception
                System.out.println("throwing");
                if(true) { 
                    throw new Exception("This is it");
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("catching");
                break;
            }

            System.out.println("inside if");
        }
        System.out.println("inside for");
    }
    System.out.println("outside for");
```

Using break is a bad programming practice. You could change the flow of code to something like this.

```
    try{
        System.out.println("inside try");
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            if(true) {
                if(true) { 
                    throw new Exception("This is it");
                }   
                System.out.println("inside if");
            }
            System.out.println("inside for");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("catching");
    }
    System.out.println("after catch");
```

Please mark your question as answered, if you see it is answered.

Answer (score 0):

Put your try/catch block around the loop instead of inside, so the loop exits on an exception:

```
try {
    for (Birra b : biAdapter.getBox()) {
        if (b.selected) {
            int quantitaInt = Integer.parseInt(b.getQuantità());
            totalAmount += b.distance * quantitaInt;
        }
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException exc) {
    System.out.println(exc);
    Toast.makeText(context, "inserisci una quantita' a \""+b.name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Alternatively, inside the catch block you can a) rethrow the exception, b) break out of the loop, or c) return from the method.